# jQuery click working only when called within a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I use `.click()` these ways, it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready($("#addPosition").click(function(event) {
  console.log("I'm in HTML .ready()");
  event.preventDefault();
}))
```

```
$($("#addPosition").click(function(event) {
  console.log("I'm in HTML $()");
  event.preventDefault();
}))
```

But if I create a function with this code and call it without parentheses, it works:

```
function doPosition() {
$("#addPosition").click(function(event) {
  console.log("I'm in function");
  event.preventDefault();
})}
$(doPosition);
```

This is the HTML part:

```
<p>Position: <input type='submit' class="btn-sm btn btn-light" id='addPosition' value='+' /></p>
```

Comment: @SMAKSS I want to understand why it is not working the ways I mentioned.

Comment: `document.ready` takes a function as an argument, not a statement.

Comment: So, you're saying, when you write syntactically valid code, it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass a function in document ready

like this

```js
//$(document).ready(() => {
//  $("#addPosition").click(function(event) {
//    console.log("I'm in HTML .ready()");
//    event.preventDefault();
//  })
//})

//or for short

$(() => {
  $("#addPosition").click(function(event) {
    console.log("I'm in HTML .ready()");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addPosition">CLICK</button>
```